# How to create sub data frames from a large data frame based on some condition?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

| Unnamed: 0 | Unnamed: 1 | Unnamed: 2 | Unnamed: 3 | Unnamed: 4 | Unnamed: 5 | Unnamed: 6 | Unnamed: 7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NaN | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| NaN | 1 | A | 2021 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| NaN | 2 | B | 2020 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| NaN | 3 | xyz | 2018 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |

**I have above data frame, I have to filter out sub dataframe using loops where the value of the cell is not null. Here For Example the sub data frame will consists row[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bk7l3m.jpg) to row [4] and column [2] to column [4]**

###### visual example

[image]

Comment: please provide a test dataframe as code/text.

Comment: @mozway PLease copy it paste it on excel.

Comment: You should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70926094/edit) your question to keep formatting

Comment: @mozway Does it make sense??

Answer (score 0):

Try using `iloc` to select subframe, based on row and column indices.

```
D1 = df.iloc[[0,1,2,3], [1,2,3]]
D2 = df.iloc[[6,7,8,9], [2,3,4,5]]
D3 = df.iloc[[5,6,7,8,9,10], [7,8,9]]
D4 = df.iloc[[17,18,19,20], [2,3,4,5,6,7,8]]
```